# Finding the difference in rotation, as an average over time unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, euler-angles

I have a ships wheel the player is able to rotate. I currently record the angle change, which is added to a total angle. I can then work out how many times the ship wheel has been turned. This all works fine.

```
void Update()
        {
            //Record Amount of Wheel Turns
            currentAngle = wheelRectTransform.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
            angleChange = Mathf.DeltaAngle(currentAngle, previousAngle);

            if ((Mathf.Abs(angle + angleChange) / 360) <=   wheelTurnsUntilRudderAtMaxAngle)
            {            
               angle += angleChange;               
            } 

            totalWheelTurns = angle / 360;
            shipStats.RudderAngle = totalWheelTurns / wheelTurnsUntilRudderAtMaxAngle;

            previousAngle = currentAngle;
        }
```

**However**, I'd also like to record the average angle change over time. Then I would be able to get an accurate idea as to wether the wheel is rotating left or right.

I have tried something simple like this

```
if (angleChange < 0)
{
     // Going Left
}
else if (angleChange > 0)
{
     // Going Right
} else
{
    // Not moving
}
```

In practice however, if the player is rotating the wheel very, very slowly the angle difference on the occasional frame is 0 and recorded as 'not moving'.

I believe the solution would be to find the average angle change over a short time so I tried to Lerp the angle to 0 over time.

```
newAngleDifference = Mathf.Lerp(angleChange, 0, Time.deltaTime * 0.2f);
```

This didn't work, it gives me the same feedback as I'm just using 'angleChange' which can be 0 anyway.

Thanks!

Jim

Comment: The whole code is a mess right now as I'm prototyping some movement. But I've put it here for you. I'm currently using some kind of Lerp to work out the direction, its not perfect but it will do.


http://pastebin.com/kGLrUYVu

Comment: Yes, z direction. No rigidbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used a Lerp to get the average.

```
    public enum WheelDirection { Left, Right, Still }

    [Header("Average Wheel Direction")]
    public float lerpTime = 0.5f; // How many seconds average over
    private WheelDirection wheelDirection; 
    private float wheelDeltaX;
    private float wheelDirectionInterpolated;
    private float currentLerpTime;

 void Update()
    {
        // Get DeltaX of objects rotation 
        // I'm interested in the Z axis, but you could change this to x/y           
        float currentAngle = transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z;
        wheelDeltaX = (currentAngle - previousAngle);

        // Reduce the Lerp percentage
        currentLerpTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (currentLerpTime > lerpTime)
        {
            currentLerpTime = lerpTime;
        }
        float perc = currentLerpTime / lerpTime;

        // Lerp!
        wheelDirectionInterpolated = (Mathf.Lerp(wheelDirectionInterpolated, wheelDeltaX, perc));

        // Wheel has finished rotating, so reset the Lerp
        if (wheelDirectionInterpolated == 0) currentLerpTime = 0;

        // Store Direction in an Enum
        if (wheelDirectionInterpolated > 0) wheelDirection = WheelDirection.Left;
        if (wheelDirectionInterpolated < 0) wheelDirection = WheelDirection.Right;
        if (wheelDirectionInterpolated == 0) wheelDirection = WheelDirection.Still;

        //This should always be at the end
        previousAngle = currentAngle;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to average anything to detect the direction of the wheel. Simply use old and new variable to find which direction the wheel is going.

```
 void Start()
 {
        StartCoroutine(wheelDIRCalculator(_wheelTransform));
 }


bool continueWheelCalculation = false;

 IEnumerator wheelDIRCalculator(Transform wheelTransform)
 {
     yield return null;

     continueWheelCalculation = true;

     float oldZAngle = 0;
     float newZAngle = 0;
     bool isIdle = false;

     oldZAngle = Mathf.Abs(wheelTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);


     while (continueWheelCalculation)
     {

         //Get new rotation
         newZAngle = Mathf.Abs(wheelTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);

         if (oldZAngle < newZAngle)
         {
             isIdle = false;
             oldZAngle = newZAngle;
             Debug.Log("Left");

             //Do something 

         }
         else if (oldZAngle > newZAngle)
         {
             isIdle = false;
             oldZAngle = newZAngle;
             Debug.Log("Right");

             //Do something 

         }
         else if (!isIdle)
         {
             isIdle = true;
             oldZAngle = newZAngle;
             Debug.Log("Idle");

             //Do something 

         }


         yield return null;
     }
 }

 void stopWheelDIRCalculator()
 {
    continueWheelCalculation = false;
 }
```